# Error when set boolean value in entity

Tags: objective-c, xmppframework

I have Chat entity which have the following attributes

[image]

When i want to set isNew attribute to 1, Xcode thread stop from execute in debug mode as in the following screenshot

[image]

My question is how to set boolean attribute of the entity in objective c?

**[Update]**

Below is Chat class interface

[image]

Comment: you can set `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]`

Comment: Already tried, also worked but has warning related to pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You property isNew is `BOOL` and you are setting `int` value to it, so its giving exception. So either you can convert your property to `int` or set `BOOL` value to it.

If you want to set 1 or 0, write one method and set values like this

```
-(BOOL) getBoolValueFrom:(int)intValue {
    return (intValue == 1) ? YES : NO;
}
```

And set value to properties like

```
chat.isNew = [self getBoolValueFrom:1];
chat.hasMedia = [self getBoolValueFrom:0];
```

Keep method `getBoolValueFrom` in same class where you are setting values to model class.